# Managing dragging on rotated elements

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

it's my first post here, so be gentle with me ;)

I'm trying to make a simple editor using MooTools (still 1.2.5 though..). Every element has a drag corner to make it resizable.

The whole thing works really great, until the element is rotated. After giving it *-moz-transform: rotate(Xdeg)* property the drags are going crazy (simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/HTg57/1/)

I know why this happens - although element is rotated all events come as the element would be in normal position.

The question is - are there somewhere any libs which can handle this problem? 
I think that I know how to solve the problem by myself, but it will take time, which I don't have.

So - are there any ready solutions to make dragging work properly when element is rotated?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you mean by 'work properly' but you really should look at this, which makes more sense (behaviour wise): http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/HTg57/2/

```
var Box = new Class({

    mEl: null,

    mDragEl: null,

    mDrag: null,

    initialize: function(pEl) {
        this.mEl = pEl;
        this.createDrag();
    },

    createDrag: function() {
        this.mDragEl = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'drag'
        }).inject(this.mEl);
        this.mEl.makeResizable({
            handle: this.mDragEl,
            limit: {
                x: [60,300],
                y: [60,300]
            }
        });
    }
});

new Box(document.getElement('div.box'));
new Box(document.getElement('div.rotate'));
```

it takes advantage of the element.makeResizable with a handle and a size limiter. it works fine when element is rotated as well. have fun...

Comment: "work properly" - what I meant is that normally (rotate(0 deg)) when I drag to right width of the element is changed. After setting rotate(-45deg) dragging right means the element has changed width and height.

What I'd like to have is that the right drag after rotation of element still changes its width only. After the rotate it's hard to make it

Comment: Well It's not the case. Look at this one - http://jsfiddle.net/j2ArR/ You can change the modifiers but it works really bad..

Comment: this is a browser rendering issue. if you rotate it less it works better. if you want better handling i suggest you use canvas.

Comment: Yeah we've thought so, but we had hope that maybe there's a solution for this without canvas. Thanks anyway.